# PowerShell - Create Search Service App Pools (All 3)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

1. How many App Pools are created when you create the Search Service Application?
2. How can I create all the Search Service Application App Pools using PowerShell and give them all unique names?

I've come across many scripts to create the search service application with a custom Admin App Pool name.  The only thing missing in all of these scripts is the ability to also name the Query App Pool like you can do in Central Admin.  I'm mainly looking to separate the App Pools and give them all unique names.

Answer (score 1):

There are two search-related service application pools: Admin and Query. Here are the lines of PowerShell I use in my scripts:

```
# Create the application pools for the Search Admin service and the Search Query service
$apppool_searchadmin = New-SPServiceApplicationPool –name $ap_search_admin –account $account_search_admin
$apppool_searchquery = New-SPServiceApplicationPool –name $ap_search_query –account $account_search_query
```

[New-SPServiceApplicationPool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607595.aspx) will return the app pool, which I use save to the two variables and use in my script later when needed. I pass it the name of the application pool and a string that contains the account name ("DOMAIN\account") for the application pool.

You can then create the search service with [New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607751%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

```
$searchApp = New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Name $searchServiceAppName -ApplicationPool $apppool_searchquery -AdminApplicationPool $apppool_searchadmin -DatabaseName $dbName
```

Comment: Could you share how you use the two $apppool variables later in your script?  The only command I've seen with an -applicationpool parameter is New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication, and like the OP I've only come across scripts that apply a single application pool here.  Is there a way in that command to specify 2 separate app pools for admin and query, or does that happen elsewhere?

Comment: ... Holy cow, thank you. I have been using that line in my scripts for over a year now and I have never noticed that the query application pool isn't used. I can't find any reference to it outside of the page created in Central Administration. The closest documentation that attempts to explain it is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2012/06/29/understanding-sharepoint-search-concepts-and-terminology-part-1.aspx, but I still can't figure out how to associate it with the query web service.

Comment: On one level that's disappointing, but on another level it's reassuring that I'm not crazy :)  I guess there really isn't a way in PowerShell to assign 2 different app pools to the admin and query portions of the Search service app then?

Comment: I see that the New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication takes two application pool parameters (ApplicationPool and AdminApplicationPool), though the documentation (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607751.aspx) is so poor I honestly have no idea what ApplicationPool is for.

Comment: Good eye! I pulled up documentation in PowerShell before and it doesn't list AdminApplicationPool in the PARAMETERS section which is what I was looking at, but now that I look at it again it does show it in the SYNTAX section and intellisense recognizes it. If I had to guess the AdminApplicationPool would be for Admin and the vanilla ApplicationPool is for Query and Site Settings. I'm not sure I'm brave enough to try it, and moreover is it even that big a deal that we really need separate app pools?

Comment: Either way I'm following up with partner support to get an answer about this, as now I have several client farms that aren't configured as expected. :S

Comment: So I went ahead and tried it. Here's the relevant script line:
$searchApp = New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Name $searchServiceAppName -ApplicationPool $queryAppPool -AdminApplicationPool $adminAppPool -DatabaseName $dbName

Worked great. Checked the properties of the service app afterwards, and the 2 app pools were properly assigned.

Comment: @shufler Can you summarize these comments and edit them into your answer? Then, we can delete the comments and save people some time.

Comment: @KitMenke done.

Answer (score 0):

1. Single Application Pool / the one you indicate when you create the S-SA
2. See script

   ```
   Function Get-SPServiceApplicationPoolByName($SPApplicationPoolName, $ManagedAccount) {
   ```

   $appPool = Get-SPServiceApplicationPool | Where {$_.Name -eq $SPApplicationPoolName}

   ```
   if($appPool -eq $null) {
       $appPool = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name $SPApplicationPoolName -Account $ManagedAccount
   }

   Return $appPool}
   ```